# How to subtract one day from current day

Tags: c#

I have two variables

```
startdate
enddate
```

In C#, I want to specify in variables startdate and enddate where the date is equal to yesterday.

For example result I want to achieve:

```
currentday = '14.09.2017'
startdate = '13.09.2017'
enddate  = '13.09.2017'
```

Comment: Have you tried `startdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now; System.DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
startdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
```

Doesn't that give you exactly what you want?

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) returns the same time yesterday. I think the OP needs DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)` for yesterday and `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)` for tomorrow.